# why doesn't linked theme work with angular material app? (but import does)

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, angular-cli

Creating an app with the angular-cli, if I link the Material theme from my index.html (following instructions from https://getmdl.io/started/):

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.deep_purple-amber.min.css">`

The complete code is in a github repo on [linked-theme-bad](https://github.com/ultrasaurus/ng-material-theme/tree/linked-theme-bad) branch where the components are not correctly styled with the theme:

[image: components appear without color and slide toggle layout is incorrect]

However, if I follow the exact instructions in the angular-cli doc to [include Angular Material](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/5066c467dfa1d924172a75a7eff0fc1380bf0161/docs/documentation/stories/include-angular-material.md) and import the style in `styles.scss`:

`@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';`

The complete code on [basic-theme-works](https://github.com/ultrasaurus/ng-material-theme/tree/basic-theme-works) branch) where the components appear correctly:

[image: purple toolbar and correct slide toggle layout]

My understanding is that the import merges into a single stylesheet and the link in the HTML page will make a separate request for the style theme. The question is *why* doesn't the linked style sheet approach work.

By the way, I'm running the app with `ng serve` but this is an isolated example from another app which also seemed to fail in the same way with files that were built with `ng build`.

Comment: Well, what do you expect when you're linking from the wrong source? In fact, you're linking from [materialdesignlite](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite), which is a completely different project from [angular-material2](https://github.com/angular/material2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're importing the CSS file from the wrong source *(material-design-lite)*. (and by the way, you're also looking at the wrong documentation. See the link below for the correct docs)

*From material.angular.io:*

> Alternatively, you can just reference the file directly. This would look something like:
>
> ```
> <link href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
> ```

[More Information on using a prebuilt theme](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-a-pre-built-theme)

Comment: I guess it wasn't obvious that the Angular Material theme was its own thing, and a completely separate implementation from Material Design Lite which is not compatible with Angular.  (Other technologies have themes on a hosted CDN, as well as ones that you can access from node_module or import.)